# How do i set a fixed path from where file can be uploaded using Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, upload

While uploading a file using angularjs, I want to restrict the folder from which the file can be selected to upload. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: conditional check will do , no fancy coding required . per say always compare the selected path with the path you expecting to be else show a message

Comment: I have used the upload from the link below.  Here when i click on the browse button, all my disks and drives are available to look into. I want to restrict that. I just want , when ever i click on Browse, the popup will directly open the folder i specify and does not allow to navigate else where.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/

Comment: oops realized a bit late you cannot get the file path (security concerns)  . so we can't compare paths to determine as we have no access to path .

Comment: Is there no way of doing this ?

Comment: no mate as far i see .